# Parallelize a "For" cycle

Tags: parallelization, conditional, for

I'm trying to parallelize a simple routine inside a "for" loop. Essentially, I need to compute the roots of a function $f(x)$ that depends on the discrete parameters $d$ and $R_0$. However, I also need to impose conditions on the results using an "if" statement. How can I parallelize this code to make it more efficient?

Here is the original code without parallelization:

```
ld = {};
Quiet[For[i = 0.1, i <= 30, i = i + 0.01,
  Clear[x, d, sole];
  d = i*R0;
  sole = FindRoot[f[x,d], {x, 0}];
  x = x /. sole[[1]] // Chop;
  If[Abs[x] < 10^(-6), AppendTo[ld, {d, 0}], 
   AppendTo[ld, {d, x}]]]]
```

Can you help me to parallelize it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use `ParallelTable` instead of `Do` + `AppendTo`. In general, better never use `AppendTo`; it was super inefficient in older *Mathematica* versions; and I think it would still break the parallelization.

```
ld = ParallelTable[
  Module[{d,x,sole},
    d = i*R0;
    sole = FindRoot[f[x, d], {x, 0}];
    x = x /. sole[[1]] // Chop;
    If[Abs[x] < 10^(-6), {d, 0}, {d, x}]
  ]
  , {i, 0.1, 30, 0.01}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that generates what you need: what you write can be simplified to a single [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) call with a tolerance of $10^{-6}$,

```
s[d_?NumericQ] := {d, Chop[x /. FindRoot[f[x, d], {x, 0}], 10^-6]};
```

Make a table, possibly parallelized:

```
ParallelTable[s[i*R0], {i, 0.1, 30, 0.01}]
```

For added versatility you may want to [memoize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) the results of the function `s` instead of storing them in a table:

```
Clear[s];
s[d_?NumericQ] := s[d] = {d, Chop[x /. FindRoot[f[x, d[i]], {x, 0}], 10^-6]};
```